# Resolve with either one in angular js route

Tags: angularjs

My code is as follows:

```
var routeRoleChecks = {
    admin: {
        auth: function(AuthenticationService) {
          return AuthenticationService.authorizeCurrentUserForRoute("admin");
        }
      },
    manager: {
        auth: function(AuthenticationService) {
          return AuthenticationService.authorizeCurrentUserForRoute("manager");
        }
      },
    hr: {
        auth: function(AuthenticationService) {
          return AuthenticationService.authorizeCurrentUserForRoute("hr");
        }
      },
    user: {
        auth: function(AuthenticationService) {
          return AuthenticationService.authorizeAuthenticatedUserForRoute();
        }
      }
  };
```

I am using like this for resolving and want to show this template if logged in is admin or manager or user, but it is working only for first one that is admin.

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/memolist", {
      template: JST["app/templates/memolist"],
      controller: "MemoListController",
      resolve: routeRoleChecks.admin || routeRoleChecks.manager || routeRoleChecks.user
    }
```

Please provide your help, how can i use resolve in or condition.

Comment: In javascript, when you write `foo || bar`, `foo` will be prefer if its value is not `null, undefined, false, or 0. That why admin is always chosen.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :-

```
resolve: {
if(!routeRoleChecks.admin){
 if(!routeRoleChecks.manager) {    
        routeRoleChecks.user
   }
}
```

}